# A multiple equality/inequalityconditions checking in if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am a newbie to programming in C++ and I have a question regarding if conditions. We are currently learning C++ at school(Using TC, i know it's an old compiler,but yeah). I am currently making a tic-tac-toe program, an undefeatable one. Now, this is my problem.

I want to check the equality of 3 variables, and run the if body only if the 3 variables are not equal to another variable.
Why is this set of code not working?

```
if(a==b==c!=d)
{
}
```

Adding parentheses doesn't help, I'm probably doing it wrong.(Please excuse my ignorance)

```
if((a==b==c)!=d)
{
}
```

Thanks in advance!
-CaptainAwesome

Answer (score 3):

You have to write each condition individually and combine them using `&&` (logical and):

```
if(a==b && b==c && c!=d)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you made this up. You can't do boolean comparisons like this.

Stick to two operands at a time and use `&&` and `||` to combine results.

I'm not entirely clear on your requirements but start with something like this:

```
if (a == b && b == c && c != d)
```

Comment: @APRocha: Perhaps spend more energy focusing on getting the logic right! `b=c`?

Comment: and i recommend add every boolean comparision between (), for legibility. example : if( (a==b) && (b==c) && (c != d) )